# salesforce Comparing Values between single lists

Tags: apex

This below methods returns all the Market__c value when queried against all  discountSchedule ID's.

Suppose i having 4 Id's in discountSchedule variable . If all the 4'ids are having same Market__c value then return Market__c else not..

**Apex Class**

```
public void updateMarketOptions() {
    marketOptions.clear();
    for (Custom_Package__c cp1 : [select Id, Market__c, state__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c ,Space_Discount__c, Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c from Custom_Package__c where Id in :discountSchedule  order by Market__c ]) {
        marketOptions.add(new SelectOption(cp1.Id, cp1.Market__c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please re-phrase your question. Its not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Santanu.. Can u chk now plzz..

Answer (score 0):

What a weird requirement! anyway! Here is what you need to do

```
public void updateMarketOptions() {
            String matchMarket;
            String id;
            Boolean firstCount = true;
            Boolean allMatched = true;
            marketOptions.clear();
            for (Custom_Package__c cp1 : [select Id, Market__c, state__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c ,Space_Discount__c, Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c from Custom_Package__c where Id in :discountSchedule  order by Market__c ]) {
                if(firstCount){
                   matchMarket = cp1.Market__c;
                   id = cp1.Id;
                   firstCount = false;
                }else{
                   if(!matchMarket.equalsIgnoreCase(cp1.Market__c)){
                        allMatched = false;
                        break;
                   }
                }
            }
if(allMatched)
  marketOptions.add(new SelectOption(Id, matchMarket));
}
```

Comment: Hi.. I am getting error -  Compile Error: Variable does not exist: cp1.Id

Comment: Oh! Rectified. Lets say there are 4 records. Now the code will add the first of the 4 records if all matched.

Comment: Hi.. Its not working..Suppose I am selecting 1st record market is populating..If i select another record whose market is same..Then it is not appearing...Can u please check..

Comment: Suppose, records are {record1,Market1}, {record2,Market1}, {record3,Market3}, What SHOULD be added to marketOption list?

Comment: according to the value u showed nothing.. Only if the values are {record1,Market1}, {record2,Market1}, {record3,Market1} .. Then add it to marketOption list...

Comment: The user can select any no of records .. but if the market values are same.. then add it to marketOption list, else no..

Comment: if market values are same, add it once or everytime??? In my previous example, what should the marketOption contain at the end? Market1 only or Market1 twice?

Comment: Market1 only once...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31373/discussion-between-sid-and-santanu-halder).